# targeting dynamic items within a stackpanel

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-8

I'm a little new to this sort of coding, but i am trying to access dynamically created `TextBlock` properties (like, TextBlock.Tag, Name, etc) within a `StackPanel` every tick of a timer. What i intend to do with each `TextBlock` is to see what its `tag` property is, and if it matches a conditoinal, for the timer to alter the `TextBlock` property in some way.

So it's a matter of finding a way to code every timer Tick: "For every `TextBlock.Tag` in StackPanel, if `TextBlock.Tag == this`, do this to the `TextBlock`."

Here is some code to help visualize what I am doing:

**Xaml code:**

```
<StackPanel Name="StackP" Margin="6,0,6,0"/>
```

**C# code:**

```
{
    for (var i = 0; i < MaxCountOfResults; ++i)
    {
        TextBlock SingleResult= new TextBlock { Text = Resultname.ToString(), FontSize = 20, Margin = new Thickness(30, -39, 0, 0) };

        //a condition to alter certain TextBlock properties.
        if (i == .... (irrelevant to this example))
        {
            SingleResult.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
            SingleResult.Tag = "00001";
        }

        //Add this dynamic TextBlock to the StackPanel StackP
        StackP.Children.Add(SingleResult);
    }

//the timer that starts when this entire function of adding the TextBlocks to the StackPanel StackP tree is done.
Atimer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(Atimer_tick), 0, 0, 100);
}


public void Atimer_tick(object state)
{
       The area where I have no idea how to reference the Children of stackpanel StackP with every timer tick. I need help :(

}
```

Thank you guys. I am still learning this and the help is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be able to use timer, but I'd recommend using `BackgroundWorker` to perform a loop instead of timer events, which could collide. Even better - use SilverLight-style animations with triggers.

On the non-UI thread you'd want to use Dispatcher call to invoke your async code back on the UI thread, something like:

```
 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
  {
    try
    {
        foreach (TextBlock txb in StackP.Children){
          txb.Text = "xyz";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine("error: "+ex);
    } 
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for this, as it is what I am looking for. However, I am oddly enough getting an InvalidCastException on the foreach line. I'll take a look at it tomorrow, as I'm too tired to walk though it now :/.

Comment: @ShaunDoty It means that you have something else than textblocks in your stackpanel. Use `OfType` in your foreach to filter them: `foreach (var txb in StackP.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())`